# does spring data jpa works with spring-core version 3

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

does spring data jpa works completely with spring-core version 3? I face issues when i use JPA repositories.

I use spring-data-jpa version 1.6.0 and spring-core 3.1.0 version.

I get following error when i use @EnableJpaRepositories in my configuration class.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ResourceLoader must not be null!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:65)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:208)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:138)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:126)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:178)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
```

Comment: Spring data JPA 1.6.0 requires, if I'm not mistaken, Spring 3.2 and works with Spring 4.0. For Spring 3.1 and earlier it probably wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data JPA 1.6.0 requires at least spring 3.2 due to api changes.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-482